# Definition - A Banach space continuously embedded in the space of distributions on the unit circle

Tags: banach-spaces, distribution-theory

What is meant by a Banach space continuously embedded in D'( $\mathbb{T}$ ), where D'($\mathbb{T}$) denotes the space of distributions on the unit circle, and how is such a space constructed? Why would we have such an embedding?

Comment: $L^p([0,1])$ embeds continuously in the distributions on $\Bbb{R/Z}$ (the space of continuous linear maps $C^\infty(\Bbb{R/Z}) \to \Bbb{C}$) because if $\|f\|_{L^p}$ is small then $\|f\|_{L^1}$ is small thus $\langle f, \phi \rangle$ is "uniformly small" for $\phi \in C^\infty(\Bbb{R/Z})$ (which is a metric space with $d(a,b) = \sum_k 2^{-k} \min(\|D^k a-D^k b\|_\infty,1)$)

Comment: Thanks reuns. Can you please elaborate a bit on "...because if $||f||_{L^p}$ is small then $||f||_{L^1}$ is small thus $\langle f, \phi \rangle$ is "uniformly small" ..." and how this relates to the continuity... Can you also say a few words on how this continuity requirement suggests that if $u_j \to u$ in $L^{p}([0,1])$ then $u_j \to u$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. I'm primarily interested in embedding the spaces $C^k(\mathbb{T}) \subset L^p(\mathbb{T})$.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I'm continuously embedded if my mapping is linear, continuous and injective (functions equal a.e. are identified)? And you show that for $f \in C^{k}(\mathbb{T})$, the map $f \mapsto T_f$ with $\langle f,\phi \rangle=T_f(\phi)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{T}} \phi(x) f(x) dx$, $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$, is continuous, using the fact that $|\langle f,\phi \rangle | \leq ||f||_{L^1} ||\phi||_{\infty} \leq ||f||_{L^p} ||1||_{L^q} ||\phi||_{\infty} \leq C ||\phi||_{\infty}$, $C>0$ , $1/p+1/q=1$, by some Hölder inequality that I found.

Comment: The condition $|\langle f,\phi \rangle | \leq C ||\phi||_{\infty}, \forall \phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$, $C>0$, is here a characterization of continuity in $D'(\mathbb{T})$ if I got it right. So what this is essentially saying is that the (semi-)norms on $D'(\mathbb{T})$ must be bounded by the sum of some number of (semi-)norms on my space of test functions $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$ for the mapping to be continuous.And this is the analogue of the definition given for a continuous embedding in the case of two normed spaces as given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_embedding

Comment: Or to be more precise, $f \in D'(\mathbb{T})$ if and only if there is $C > 0$ and a non negative integer $N$ such that $|\langle f, \phi \rangle| \leq C \sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} ||\partial^{\alpha} \phi ||_{\infty}$, $\forall \phi \in D(\mathbb{T})$.